# What's the difference between the Adaptec Hybrid RAID and MaxCache Using SSDs?

Tags: ssd, raid, sata, sas

From this line of controllers

- http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/products/controllers/hardware/

Explained further here

- http://www.adaptec.com/nr/pdfs/product_overview.pdf

My interpretation is as follows:

The Hybrid RAID involves an SSD and Non-SSD drive together in a RAID-1 configuration. Writes occur as normal, mirrored on both drives. However the controller only reads from the SSD (assuming it's non-degraded) returning data much faster. As such the Non-SSD becomes a *backup only* drive.

In contrast, the MaxCache can use one or more SSD drives to merely cache *hot* data. You can assemble a RAID-5/6 of slow SATA drives in the background, using the SSD as a dynamic cache of frequently accessed data.

The main contrast I suppose is

1. The Hybrid RAID requires SSDs for *all* your data
2. The MaxCache supports any sized Slow-RAID supported by a single SSD, the size is proportional *only* to how much data you wish cached.

Comment: You've described the main difference(s) in your own question.  What is it you are looking for an answer to?

Comment: Just looking to confirm my interpretation, perhaps I've missed something.